# Mobile keyboard not triggered using guacamole-common-js in browser

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rdp, guacamole, guacamole-common.js

I'm working on a project that aims to render a RDP connection in a browser (mobile and desktop) using Apache Guacamole. For the UI, I'm using ReactJS and guacamole-common-js. Everything works as expected on both platforms, other than the keyboard not being triggered on mobile browser.

```
const GuacdPage = (props) => {
  const {connectionParam, onError, onStateChange, onSync} = props;

  const [guacd, setGuacd] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('initial effect starting')
    renderDisplay();
  }, []);

  const renderDisplay = () => {
    const tunnel = new Guacamole.WebSocketTunnel("/api/ws");
    const client = new Guacamole.Client(tunnel);

    client.onerror = onError;
    client.onsync = onSync;
    client.onstatechange = onStateChange

    // Get display div from document
    const displayEle = document.getElementById("display");

    // Add client to display div
    const element = client.getDisplay().getElement();
    displayEle.appendChild(element);

    client.connect("connection=" + connectionParam);
    const display = client.getDisplay();

    const sink = new Guacamole.InputSink();
    displayEle.appendChild(sink.getElement());
    sink.focus();

    const keyboard = new Guacamole.Keyboard(sink.getElement());

    keyboard.onkeydown = (keysym) => {
      client.sendKeyEvent(1, keysym);
    };
    keyboard.onkeyup = (keysym) => {
      client.sendKeyEvent(0, keysym);
    };
    const mouse = new Guacamole.Mouse(element);

    mouse.onmousedown = mouse.onmouseup = function(mouseState) {
      sink.focus();
      client.sendMouseState(mouseState);
    };

    mouse.onmousemove = function(mouseState) {
      sink.focus();
      client.getDisplay().showCursor(false);
      mouseState.x = mouseState.x / display.getScale();
      mouseState.y = mouseState.y / display.getScale();
      client.sendMouseState(mouseState);
    };
    const touch = new Guacamole.Mouse.Touchscreen(element);

    touch.onmousedown = touch.onmousemove = touch.onmouseup = function(state) {
      client.sendMouseState(state);
    };
    window.addEventListener("resize", handleResize);

    return () => {
        client.disconnect()
        window.removeEventListener("resize", handleResize)
    }

  };

  const handleResize = () => {
    const width = document.body.offsetWidth
    const height = document.body.offsetHeight
    guacd.client.sendSize(width, height);
}

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="container">
        <div id="display" />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default GuacdPage;
```

I have tried two solutions:

1. Using an [InputSink](https://guacamole.apache.org/doc/guacamole-common-js/Guacamole.InputSink.html)
2. Using an [OnScreenKeyboard](https://guacamole.apache.org/doc/gug/guacamole-common-js.html#on-screen-keyboard)

The 2nd method renders a "list of keys" on screen with no effect, and the 1st does nothing - I think the issue has to do how the focus is being handled. I'm not sure if I need to be creating a dedicated input field for the input sink.

Any input would be greatly appreciated. Thanks